# "By the end of today" or "By the end of the day"

Tags: expressions, idioms, expression-choice

Which is the correct (or more correct) expression:

- By the end of today
- By the end of the day

My context is a promise to send an email today (i.e., before tomorrow).

Comment: [Why was the question “By the end of today” or “By the end of the day” closed as opinion-based?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15017/17712)

Comment: reposted on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/288372/3023

Answer (score 2):

I believe either is acceptable.  I have always used "by end of business" which normally means by 5pm.  I think that it depends on who you are sending the email to.  If it is a superior you might want to reconsider and define an exact time deadline.  If it is to a subordinate giving a general time frame like end of today or end of the day would be fine.

Comment: [“Close of business”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=close+of+business%2Cend+of+business&year_start=1860) and [“by close of business”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+close+of+business%2Cby+end+of+business&year_start=1890) are ***much** more* common.